# Price range query returns inaccurate results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form where user can search for products within their specified price range.
Wherein I have 2 input boxes 1 is for the starting range and the other is for the ending range.

I have 3 products stores in my database table. With prices `2300.0000`, `1200.0000`, `1000.5000` respectively.

Im having a problem with selecting values within the inputted price range. The problem is that, when I input values like

1. `100` starting range to `1100` ending range. The products with `1200.0000`
   and `1000.5000` is being displayed instead of only the `1000.5000`
   product.
2. `0` starting range to `1100` ending range or `1000.50` ending range. The
   products with `1200.0000` and `1000.5000` is being displayed instead of
   only the `1000.5000` product.
3. `1100` starting range. Only the product with `2300.0000` is being
   displayed instead of both `2300.0000` and `1200.0000`. But when the
   starting values is less than or equal `500` all the 3 products is
   being displayed.

This is the code i am using.

```
function db_prepare_input($string)
{
    if (is_string($string)) {
        return trim(stripslashes($string));
    } elseif (is_array($string)) {
        reset($string);
        while (list($key, $value) = each($string)) {
            $string[$key] = db_prepare_input($value);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    } else {
        return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    }
}

$pricefrom_key = db_prepare_input(number_format($_GET['pricefrom'], 4, '.', ''));
$priceto_key = db_prepare_input(number_format($_GET['priceto'], 4, '.', ''));

// Price Range
if (!empty($_GET['pricefrom']) && !empty($_GET['priceto'])) {
    $price_range = " having price >= ".$pricefrom_key." and price <= ".$priceto_key;
}
elseif(empty($_GET['pricefrom']) && !empty($_GET['priceto']))
{
    $price_range = " having price >= 0 and price <= ".$priceto_key;
}

elseif(!empty($_GET['pricefrom']) && empty($_GET['priceto']))
{
    $price_range = " having price >= ".$pricefrom_key;
}

elseif(!empty($_GET['pricefrom']) && !empty($_GET['priceto']))
{
    $price_range = "";
}

$catglobal_sql = "select p.blog_id, p.global_category_id, p.products_id, p.products_currency, p.products_type, p.products_name, p.products_description, p.products_quantity, p.products_model, p.products_image, p.products_price, p.products_date_added, p.products_last_modified, p.products_date_available, p.products_weight, p.products_status, p.products_tax_class_id, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_ordered, p.specials_new_products_price, p.specials_date_added, p.specials_last_modified, p.expires_date, p.date_status_change, p.status, p.display_product, case when (p.specials_new_products_price > 0 or p.specials_new_products_price != 0000-00-00 and p.expires_date > Now() and p.status != 0) then p.specials_new_products_price else p.products_price end price from ".TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS." p INNER JOIN ".TABLE_STORES." s ON s.blog_id = p.blog_id where MATCH (p.products_name,p.products_description) AGAINST ('%".$search_key."%') OR p.products_name like '%".$search_key."%' and s.countries_id = '168' ".$search_cat." and p.display_product = '1' and p.products_status = '1' ".$price_range." order by p.products_date_added DESC, p.products_name";
```

I tried, adding `die($catglobal_sql);` and the result is,

```
select p.blog_id, p.global_category_id, p.products_id, p.products_currency, p.products_type, p.products_name, p.products_description, p.products_quantity, p.products_model, p.products_image, p.products_price, p.products_date_added, p.products_last_modified, p.products_date_available, p.products_weight, p.products_status, p.products_tax_class_id, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_ordered, p.specials_new_products_price, p.specials_date_added, p.specials_last_modified, p.expires_date, p.date_status_change, p.status, p.display_product, case when (p.specials_new_products_price > 0 or p.specials_new_products_price != 0000-00-00 and p.expires_date > Now() and p.status != 0) then p.specials_new_products_price else p.products_price end price from wp_global_products_table p INNER JOIN wp_blogs s ON s.blog_id = p.blog_id where MATCH (p.products_name,p.products_description) AGAINST ('%cotton%') OR p.products_name like '%cotton%' and s.countries_id = '168' and p.products_currency = 'php' and p.display_product = '1' and p.products_status = '1' and p.products_type = 'a' having price >= 0 and price <= 1200.0000 order by p.products_date_added DESC, p.products_name
```

What seems to be the problem??

Comment: What is the price field in the database defined as? Is it numeric, or text? It looks like your search is searching alphabetically rather than numerically....

Comment: what field type are the prices?

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a HAVING clause instead of adding the price information onto the WHERE clause?

Comment: @andrewsi i guess because i use, `case when (p.specials_new_products_price > 0 or p.specials_new_products_price != 0000-00-00 and p.expires_date > Now() and p.status != 0) then p.specials_new_products_price else p.products_price end price` someone told me to use `having clause`

Comment: That's fair enough; it's not something I've used very often - there's a comment in the docs about only using it in an aggregate clause, and I've no idea if `case` counts... It might be worth bumping it into the WHERE clause to see if it changes the results?

Comment: I agree with @andrewsi. Don't use `HAVING` unless you have no choice (as in, you get a syntax error otherwise).

Comment: The debugging trick I frequently use is right after you set `$catglobal_sql`, add `die($catglobal_sql);`. This will allow you to see the actual SQL generated so you can check for obvious mistakes.

Comment: I tried changing `having` to `and` but it returns no results now.

Comment: @yakatz i updated my post above with adding `die($catglobal_sql);` and it seems that my sql generated is ok(as for me)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.. Its on the case.. i have modified it to `case when p.specials_new_products_price >= 0.0000 and p.expires_date > Now() and p.status != 0 then p.specials_new_products_price else p.products_price end price`

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you doing with this line..

```
$price_range = " having price >= ".$pricefrom_key." and price <= ".$priceto_key;
```

Shouldn't you just set the $price_range i.e.:

```
if (!empty($_GET['pricefrom']) && !empty($_GET['priceto']))
```

{

```
      if($price_range >= $pricefrom_key && $price_range <= $priceto_key)
      {
      echo "you are in the pricerange from" .$pricefrom_key." to ".$priceto_key;
      } 
//etc......
}
```

Edit:  since some did not get my answer, this was just to point into the right direction. It does not matter if us use "echo" statement or SQL query, you still need to specify the range properly. The statement:

```
$price_range = " having price >= ".$pricefrom_key." and price <= ".$priceto_key;
```

.. pretty much says: price range = some text . number . some text . number
the < = > operators are in " " which means TEXT and they will be ignored. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: He is trying to build a SQL query, not create output.

Comment: It does not matter. His price range specification is still wrong. My example was just to point to the right direction. If he needs SQL query the he should ask for it. see my edit above.....